# How can I login to Github with the egit-github Java library?

Tags: java, android, github-api

I use the library [egit-github](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core)

I use gradle to import the library

```
    compile 'org.eclipse.mylyn.github:org.eclipse.egit.github.core:3.7.0.201502260915-r'
```

And I try the code just like the example in the readme.md in the above link.

```
 GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient();  // this line throw exception
 client.setCredentials("xxxxxx", "3xxxxxxx");
```

But it throw exception like below

```
07-02 21:08:28.620  30789-32145/com.example.quinn.githubknife E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12108
Process: com.example.quinn.githubknife, PID: 30789
java.lang.VerifyError: org/eclipse/egit/github/core/client/GitHubClient
        at com.example.quinn.githubknife.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:31)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I hope some kind people can help me.

Comment: Are you using the library in an Android app???

Comment: Seems like `egit-github` is not Dalvik compatible, probably because Dalvik isn't actually a proper, fully implemented JVM and doesn't support full Java spec.

Comment: @Codebender    I use it in an Android app,

Comment: If I am not wrong, the library is used for communicating with Github API's (to pull source code, commit source... etc)... Are you planning to pull out source code to an android device and develop/build there??? If you can specify what you are trying to achieve we may be able to help you more...

Comment: @Codebender I try to use this library to login Github and load repo and follwers .I think the core problem is "java.lang.VerifyError:".this errer  is always throw when i try to run "new GIthubClient();"I   think somewhere is wrong where I  import the library by gradle.

Comment: @Codebender Finally,I fix it.I just need to import GSON with gradle,beacuse the egit-github library dependson GSON..What a pity,the official doc doesn't warn us this point explictly.

Comment: @ZilMike, Glad it worked... You can add it as an answer and mark it so too so it helps future devs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just add gson into the gradle file and fix this problem.Because the egit-github library depends on GSON.

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'org.eclipse.mylyn.github:org.eclipse.egit.github.core:3.7.0.201502260915-r'
```